# extract text with grep and special characters

Tags: r

I am attempting to extract specific lines from a text file.  I usually do this with `grep`.  However, I have encountered a situation in which my usual approach is not working.  An example block of text is:

```
my.text <- 'junk 1
junk 2
junk 3
     |  a           b           c           d           e           f       
 ----+------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
   1 |  1     2    3    4    5    6   
     |  6     5    4    3    2    1      '   

my.data <- readLines(textConnection(my.text))
```

I want to extract:

```
   1 |  1     2    3    4    5    6   
     |  6     5    4    3    2    1
```

The following code works, but is not general among files:

```
b.top <- 'junk 3'
my.data  <- my.data[(grep(b.top, my.data)+4):length(my.data)]
```

The following code would be general among files, but does not work:

```
b.top    <- ' ----+------------------------------------------------------------------------'
my.data  <- my.data[(grep(b.top, my.data)+2):length(my.data)]
```

How can I get the general approach to work?  I do not think `-` and `+` require an escape character, but I might be wrong.  Thank you for any advice.

**EDIT**

Ideally I would like to extract:

```
1     2    3    4    5    6   
6     5    4    3    2    1
```

However, that might be a follow-up question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your original code, you just need to escape the `+` with a double backslash `\\`.

```
> b.top    <- ' ----+------------------------------------------------------------------------'
> grep(b.top, my.data)
integer(0)
> b.top    <- ' ----\\+------------------------------------------------------------------------'
> grep(b.top, my.data)
[1] 5
> my.data[(grep(b.top, my.data)+2):length(my.data)]
[1] "   1 |  1     2    3    4    5    6   "    "     |  6     5    4    3    2    1      "
>
```

`+` is a qualifier that means 1 or more, so in the original expression `-+` was most likely interpreted as one or more `-`s instead of what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest thing in the world, but you can use a combination of `gsub`, `grep`, and `strsplit` to get your "ideal" answer.

```
> g1 <- grep("[0-9]( )", my.data, value = TRUE)
> g2 <- gsub("(.*\\|[[:space:]]+)|([[:space:]]+) ", "", g1)
> lapply(strsplit(g2, ""), as.numeric)
## [[1]]
## [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6

## [[2]]
## [1] 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If line you like always comes two line after the `----`, this `awk` may work:

```
awk -F\| '/----/ {f=NR} f && (NR==f+2 || NR==f+3) {print $2}' file
  1     2    3    4    5    6
  6     5    4    3    2    1      '
```

Comment: Thank you.  That does not look like familiar `R` code, but I can try it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
my.text <- 'junk 1
junk 2
junk 3
     |  a           b           c           d           e           f       
 ----+------------------------------------------------------------------------
     |
   1 |  1     2    3    4    5    6   
     |  6     5    4    3    2    1      '   

my.data <- readLines(textConnection(my.text))

my.data  <- my.data[(which(grepl("----", my.data)==TRUE)+2):length(my.data)]
my.data

[1] "   1 |  1     2    3    4    5    6   "    "     |  6     5    4    3    2    1      "
```

Here is code to convert to the ideal result:

```
my.data2 <- substr(my.data, 7, nchar(my.data))
my.data2

my.data3 <- read.table(text = my.data2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header = FALSE, strip.white=TRUE)
my.data3

  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1  1  2  3  4  5  6
2  6  5  4  3  2  1
```